# type ViewController doesn't conform to protocol

Tags: swift

i'm trying to implement this solution to handle multiple segue identifiers with protocol [Protocol-Oriented Segue Identifiers in Swift](https://www.natashatherobot.com/protocol-oriented-segue-identifiers-swift/) , but i got this error:

> type 'ViewController', doesn't conform to protocol 'SegueHandlerType'

Here is the code:

```
protocol SegueHandlerType {
    associatedtype SegueIdentifier: RawRepresentable
}
extension SegueHandlerType where Self: UIViewController, SegueIdentifier.RawValue == String {

    func performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: SegueIdentifier,
                                    sender: AnyObject?) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier.rawValue, sender: sender)
    }

    func segueIdentifierForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) -> SegueIdentifier {

        // still have to use guard stuff here, but at least you're
        // extracting it this time
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier,
            segueIdentifier = SegueIdentifier(rawValue: identifier) else {
                fatalError("Invalid segue identifier \(segue.identifier).") }

        return segueIdentifier
    }
}
```

i copy/pasted the solution but still the same result. and the strangest thing is that when i downloaded the project from the GitHub, it works fine. this drives me nuts.

the error: [image]

Comment: 1. The code you show does not include a `ViewController`. 2. where does the error occur?

Comment: @i6x86 the error you're getting means you haven't implemented the required methods and variables of `SegueHandlerType`

Comment: @i6x86 are you sure that you have an `enum` called `SegueIdentifier` in your ViewController?

Comment: thanks @kabiroberai i'm stupid, this is the answer. i didn't implemented the methods. thank you.

Comment: @i6x86 mind if I post it as an actual answer? People will know that the question has been answered then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may be confusingly worded, but what it means is that you need to make sure that you are implementing the methods and variables (only the `SegueIdentifier` enum in this case) in your `ViewController` class. Do that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol `SegueHandlerType` contains the line `SegueIdentifier: RawRepresentable`. That means that the class conforming to the protocol has to define a nested type `SegueIdentifier`.

The tutorial includes the following for that matter:

```
// the compiler will now complain if you don't have this implemented
// you need this to conform to SegueHandlerType
enum SegueIdentifier: String {
    case TheRedPillExperience
    case TheBluePillExperience
}
```

If you add that code the compiler will not longer complain.

```
class ViewCtr : UIViewController, SegueHandlerType {
    enum SegueIdentifier: String {
        case YourSegueIdentifiersGoHere
    }
}
```

Comment: @i6x86 Does it work now? If my answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking on the checkmark on its left

Comment: yes it works, and i'm so sorry, but if you read the comments (below my stupid question), you'll notice that technically @kabiroberai answered first, so i choose his answer. thank you very much!